# i am getting only one document from the collection of firebase for different id

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
 const { id } = useParams();
  const [detailData, setDetailData] = useState({});
  useEffect(() => {
    const q = query(collection(db, "movie"));
    onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
        if (doc.exists) {
           setDetailData(doc.data());
        } else {
          console.log("no doc");
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error:", error);`enter code here`
      });
    });
  }, [id]);
```

how can i pass id of document in this code tried lots of tutorials and official documentation also .

Answer (score 0):

QuerySnapshot.docs returns an array of QuerydocumentSnapshot which has an id field:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot

This is located outside of the doc.data field. Doc.data contains the data in your DB object.